# Google Charts - Material Bar Chart, Convert Options

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use Material Bar Chart, because i want to change K format for thousands at the Vaxis data. I want to show as 1000 not like 1k. When I use the following code for the chart, it seems okey, but i cannot customize Vaxis;

```
    <script>
Array.prototype.insert = function ( index, item ) {
    this.splice( index, 0, item );
};
function all(arr2,test){
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        if(arrGrp[0].length == 2)
        {
            arr2.push([' ', null]);
        }
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr2);
        console.log("ARR: " + arr2);

        var options = {
            title: 'Min: ' + min +' Max: ' + max ,
            bars:'vertical',
            bar: {groupWidth: "25%"},
            height: 400,
            vAxis: {
                format: 'decimal',
                minValue: min,
                maxValue: max,
                viewWindowMode : 'explicit',
                viewWindow: {
                    max:max,
                    min:min
                },}};

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
var arrGrp=[];
</script>
```

And I populate my data as follows;

```
@{
var grpHeader2 = Model.GroupBy(r => new { r.GradeId, r.Grade }).ToList();
<script>
    var arr = [];
    var rowIndex=0;
    arr.insert(rowIndex,'Date');
    rowIndex++;
    @foreach (var grpHeaderItem in grpHeader2)
    {
    <text>
    arr.insert(rowIndex,'@(Html.Raw(grpHeaderItem.Key.Grade))');
    rowIndex++;
    </text>
    }
    arrGrp.push(arr);
    max='@(Model.Max(r=>r.MaxScore).HasValue ? Model.Max(r => r.MaxScore) : -1 )';
    min='@(Model.Min(r=>r.MinScore).HasValue ? Model.Min(r => r.MinScore) : -1 )';
</script>

}
@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(r => new { r.PlannedDate }))
{
<script>
    var arr = [];
    var rowIndex=0;
    @*arr.insert(rowIndex,new Date(@item.Key.PlannedDate.Year,@item.Key.PlannedDate.Month,@item.Key.PlannedDate.Day));*@
    arr.insert(rowIndex,'@item.Key.PlannedDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")');
    rowIndex++;
    @foreach (var grpHeaderItem in grpHeader2)
    {
        <text>
    arr.insert(rowIndex,@(Model.Where(r=>r.PlannedDate == item.Key.PlannedDate && grpHeaderItem.Key.GradeId == r.GradeId).Select(r=>r.GradeMin).FirstOrDefault()));
    rowIndex++;
    </text>
    }
    arrGrp.push(arr);

</script>
}

@{
<script>

    all(arrGrp,'@(Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exam))');
</script>
```

Screen shot is [1]: https://imgyukle.com/i/1.xElyj "before - working but no customization"
But when  change code

chart.draw(data, options);

to

chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

It looks like; [2]: https://imgyukle.com/i/2.xE348 "nothing working"

Can someone please help me what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

when you draw the chart **without** --> `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions`,
the chart ignores the options for --> `vAxis.viewWindow.min` & `max`,
so the chart draws fine...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Reading & Writing', 'Math', 'Total'],
    ['07.08.2018', 220, 230, 450, 610, 1060]
  ]);

  var min = -1;
  var max = -1;

  var options = {
    title: 'Min: ' + min +' Max: ' + max ,
    bars:'vertical',
    bar: {groupWidth: "25%"},
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
      format: 'decimal',
      minValue: min,
      maxValue: max,
      viewWindowMode : 'explicit',
      viewWindow: {
        max:max,
        min:min
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, (options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

when you draw the chart **with** --> `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions`,
it uses the `min` & `max` options, but according to the picture,
`min` & `max` are both set to --> `-1`,
there are no rows that meet this criteria,
so the chart is blank...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Reading & Writing', 'Math', 'Total'],
    ['07.08.2018', 220, 230, 450, 610, 1060]
  ]);

  var min = -1;
  var max = -1;

  var options = {
    title: 'Min: ' + min +' Max: ' + max ,
    bars:'vertical',
    bar: {groupWidth: "25%"},
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
      format: 'decimal',
      minValue: min,
      maxValue: max,
      viewWindowMode : 'explicit',
      viewWindow: {
        max:max,
        min:min
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

note: there are several options that are not supported by *Material* charts.
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

this includes --> `vAxis.minValue`, `vAxis.maxValue`, & `vAxis.format`

but `vAxis.viewWindow.min` & `max` work, and is the same as `vAxis.minValue` & `vAxis.maxValue`

to format the y-axis, use --> `vAxes` (with an *e*) -- format each axis separately, here you only have one

```
vAxes: {
  0: {
    format: 'decimal'
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Reading & Writing', 'Math', 'Total'],
    ['07.08.2018', 220, 230, 450, 610, 1060]
  ]);

  var min = 0;
  var max = 1200;

  var options = {
    title: 'Min: ' + min +' Max: ' + max ,
    bars:'vertical',
    bar: {groupWidth: "25%"},
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max:max,
        min:min
      }
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {
        format: 'decimal'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```